# Problema al generar un PDF

Tags: pdf, botón, parametros

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código que me sirve para determinar la salida de un PDF utilizando FPDF en base a la selección desde un par de botones

```html
<form method="post" id="impresionResguardoSCP" name="impresionResguardoSCP" class="DataTables_sort_wrapper bd-example-row text-center" action="resguardoIndividualSCP.php">
                                            
<button id="btndescargaResguardo" name="boton"  type="submit"  class="btn btn-success -download" value="DescargarResguardo"  title="DESCARGA DE RESGUARDO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></button>
<button id="btnimprimirResguardo" name="boton"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success -print" value="ImprimirResguardo"   title="IMPRESION DE RESGUARDO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></button>
 <input  id="access_token" type="hidden" name="access_token" value="<?=$empleado_UnidadUsuario?>" />
 </form>
```

el archivo que recibe los valores o parametros es este" ImprimirResguardoSCP.php"

```html
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

include 'inc/PDF/plantilla_ImprimirResguardoSCP_inc.php';

if (isset ($_POST['boton']) || ($_POST['access_token'])) {
    //echo $_POST['boton'];
    //echo $_POST['access_token'];
    $botonPresionado=strip_tags($_POST['boton']);
    $Numero_Empleado=strip_tags($_POST['access_token']);


    switch ($botonPresionado){


        case 'DescargarResguardo': //"Si entra aquí descarga el pdf en archivo con el nombre del empleado"

            $pdf = new PDF('L');
            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(1, 30);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 5);
            $pdf->Header();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 5);
            // Títulos de las columnas
            $header = array('No.', 'MUNICIPIO', 'NUMERO_ACTIVO', 'SUBNUMERO', 'DESCRIPCIÓN DEL BIEN', 'MATERIAL', 'COLOR', 'MARCA', 'MODELO', 'SERIE', 'ESTADO DEL BIEN');
            // Carga de la tabla
            $pdf->ActivosTable($header);


            $instanciaPersistenciaRecursosHumanos = new recursos_humanos();
            $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos = new n_recursos_humanos();
            $resultadolistaRecursosHumanos = $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos->n_Consulta_Usuario($Numero_Empleado);
            $totalResultadoListaRecursoshumanos = count($resultadolistaRecursosHumanos);
            for ($rh = 0; $rh < $totalResultadoListaRecursoshumanos; $rh++) {
                $nombre_EmpleadoRH = $resultadolistaRecursosHumanos[$rh]->getCadenaNombre();
            }

            $pdf->Output('RESGUARDO INDIVIDUAL_' . $nombre_EmpleadoRH . '.pdf', 'D');
            break;

        case 'ImprimirResguardo': //"Si entra aquí muestra el pdf en pantalla con el nombre del empleado"
            include 'inc/PDF/plantilla_ImprimirResguardoSCP_inc.php';
            $pdf = new PDF('L');
            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(1, 30);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 5);
            $pdf->Header();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 5);
            // Títulos de las columnas
            $header = array('No.', 'MUNICIPIO', 'NUMERO_ACTIVO', 'SUBNUMERO', 'DESCRIPCIÓN DEL BIEN', 'MATERIAL', 'COLOR', 'MARCA', 'MODELO', 'SERIE', 'ESTADO DEL BIEN');
            // Carga de la tabla
            $pdf->ActivosTable($header);
            $instanciaPersistenciaRecursosHumanos = new recursos_humanos();
            $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos = new n_recursos_humanos();
            $resultadolistaRecursosHumanos = $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos->n_Consulta_Usuario($Numero_Empleado);
            $totalResultadoListaRecursoshumanos = count($resultadolistaRecursosHumanos);
            for ($rh = 0; $rh < $totalResultadoListaRecursoshumanos; $rh++) {
                $nombre_EmpleadoRH = $resultadolistaRecursosHumanos[$rh]->getCadenaNombre();
            }

            $pdf->Output('RESGUARDO INDIVIDUAL_' . $nombre_EmpleadoRH . '.pdf', 'I');
            break;
    }


}
?>
```

hasta aquí funciona bien,  como se vera en el código estoy incluyendo un archivo denominado "plantilla_ImprimirResguardoSCP_inc.php" el cual debería recibir un parámetro, pero no he logrado hacer que lo reciba.

```html
//put your code here
require('librerias_auxiliares/fpdf182/fpdf.php');

include 'master/clases/cargar_clases.php';

    class PDF extends FPDF
    {

        function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            $this->Image('imagenes/logos/FondoResguardo2.jpg', 0, 0, 300, 0);
            // Arial bold 15
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
            $instanciaPersistenciaRecursosHumanos = new recursos_humanos();
            $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos = new n_recursos_humanos();
            $resultadolistaRecursosHumanos = $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos->n_Consulta_Usuario($Numero_Empleado);  <-- "Aqui es donde necesito que reciba un valor"
            $totalResultadoListaRecursoshumanos = count($resultadolistaRecursosHumanos);

// "no agrego el codigo restante ya que es mucho..."
}
```

No encuentro la manera de pasar el parámetro "$Numero_Empleado" para realizar la consulta, es conveniente mencionar que este código ya funciona adecuadamente en otro segmento de el sistema, solo que en la otra sección del sistema donde si funciona recibe directamente el valor desde una variable de session,  la necesidad es otra, que un usuario logeado, en base a sus permisos pueda imprimir la información de otro usuario, que es el valor que requiero en este momento pasar para que realice la consulta y muestre la información requerida.  Ese valor es el mismo que estaría recibiendo desde los botones en el primer archivo  ImprimirResguardoSCP.php

Agradecería cualquier aportación que ayude a resolver este inconveniente

Answer (score 0):

Quizás no sea lo mas prolijo pero después de leer muchos blogs una idea fue la única alternativa, crear una variable de sesión aunque en este caso ya tenia la sesión inicializada por lo que no es necesario incluir todo el código,lo que se hizo fue colocar

`$_SESSION['Nombre_variable']=$_POST['access_token'];`

del lado del archivo donde se reciben los POST , ya con el valor asignado a esta variable, se coloca en el archivo requerido, de igual manera ya tiene sesión abierta por lo que no hay necesidad de poner nada mas que esta linea `$_SESSION['Nombre_variable']` una vez que se recibe este valor se procede a añadir en las lineas requeridas

```
$resultadolistaRecursosHumanos = $instanciaNegocioRecursoshumanos->n_Consulta_Usuario($_SESSION['Nombre_variable'])
```

y listo funciona sin problema.

Si alguien tiene una mejor alternativa se aceptan ideas.

Saludos